# Get Wikidata Dump with countries and attributes

Tags: wikidata, sparql

I'm trying to write a SPARQL-query for wikidata, returning all European countries with their most recent properties (population, area, average income, age of retirement and human development index). One country should fill one line because I would like to cluster this data later.

I wrote the following query but it didn't work as expected.

```
SELECT ?countryLabel ?population ?populationDate ?area ?areaDate ?income ?incomeDate ?retirementAge ?retirementAgeDate ?hdi ?hdiDate WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
  OPTIONAL {
    SELECT ?country (MAX(?popDate) AS ?latestPopDate) ?population WHERE {
      ?country p:P1082 ?popStmt.
      ?popStmt ps:P1082 ?population.
      ?popStmt pq:P585 ?popDate.
    } GROUP BY ?country ?population
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    SELECT ?country (MAX(?areaDate) AS ?latestAreaDate) ?area WHERE {
      ?country p:P2046 ?areaStmt.
      ?areaStmt ps:P2046 ?area.
      ?areaStmt pq:P585 ?areaDate.
    } GROUP BY ?country ?area
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    SELECT ?country (MAX(?incomeDate) AS ?latestIncomeDate) ?income WHERE {
      ?country p:P3529 ?incomeStmt.
      ?incomeStmt ps:P3529 ?income.
      ?incomeStmt pq:P585 ?incomeDate.
    } GROUP BY ?country ?income
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    SELECT ?country (MAX(?retirementAgeDate) AS ?latestRetirementAgeDate) ?retirementAge WHERE {
      ?country p:P8772 ?retirementAgeStmt.
      ?retirementAgeStmt ps:P8772 ?retirementAge.
      ?retirementAgeStmt pq:P585 ?retirementAgeDate.
    } GROUP BY ?country ?retirementAge
  }
  OPTIONAL {
    SELECT ?country (MAX(?hdiDate) AS ?latestHdiDate) ?hdi WHERE {
      ?country p:P1081 ?hdiStmt.
      ?hdiStmt ps:P1081 ?hdi.
      ?hdiStmt pq:P585 ?hdiDate.
    } GROUP BY ?country ?hdi
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
} ORDER BY ?countryLabel
```

How would you write such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some of the geographical data (e.g. area) easily from [geonames.org](https://www.geonames.org/countries/). This list comprises *all* world countries though.

Perhaps join that list with this query to get the current list of 47 souvereign states in Europe, according to Wikidata, https://w.wiki/6nnb,

```
PREFIX wd:       <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt:      <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX p:        <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps:       <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX pq:       <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/>
PREFIX rdfs:     <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd:      <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX bd:       <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX schema:   <http://schema.org/>

SELECT ?country ?countryQ ?countryLabel WHERE {
  ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078;
    wdt:P30 wd:Q46.
  BIND (xsd:integer(REPLACE(STR(?country), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q", "" )) as ?countryQ)
  FILTER(?countryQ < 2000) # filter "Kingdom of " duplicates; UK constituent countries, disputed territories, etc.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY ASC(?countryQ) ASC( ?countryLabel)
```

Does this list fit your needs or do you define Eurpe differently (e.g. only  Western European countries)?

As for retirement age, you proposed query fragment  `?country p:P8772 ?retirementAgeStmt. ...`  makes no sense to me. `p:P8772` is "has blogger id". (?)

I suggest that you search some specialized databases such as [data.europa.eu](https://data.europa.eu/en). It also has a (difficult to use) SPARQL interface.
Retirement ages can be found there via classic search forms, though, example: [Average age at which not employed persons started receiving a retirement pension - by sex and main reason for retirement or early retirement](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/api/dissemination/sdmx/2.1/data/lfso_06reasagps?format=tsv&compressed=false) , textfile.